# How to define route for multiple areas in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Initially I had only one area and I wanted that as the default route so I configured it like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{area=Product}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

and it was working fine. Now I want to include another area "Order" and configured the route like:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
     routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{area=Product}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     routes.MapRoute(
            name: "orderRoute",
            template: "{area=Order}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

and in Home controller of Order area:

```
[Area("Order")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

Now when I hit `https://localhost:44632/order` I am getting 404 not found but `https://localhost:44632/product` is working fine. I also tried to configure orderRoute before default route but still got same results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I make a [demo](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpKn7su6jmAgQYMczYvj8Dna0xh) using your code and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
It looks correct. Just needs a change. You need to add default route in the end not as the first route. just interchange and it should work.


With .net core, following is needed to be added in the startup file if you are adding an area:

     app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });

After that you can just simply mark your area and route in the controller, i.e
     [Area("Order")]
     [Route("order")]
```